# METEOR - Automatically increment order numbers

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

What I need to do is use either collection-2 or another package to automatically create a new order number, incremented from the last order number used.

i.e. Starting off with PO123456, when I save this order, the next time I make a new PO, it automatically generates the number PO123457.

I've been looking for a good example or tutorial, but I'm not able to find one.

Comment: Someone recommended I check out the package konecty:mongo-counter, but I'm still having a hard time getting the hang of it.  Any tutorials that can help me learning how to incorporate the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Using `konecty:mongo-counter` in conjuntion with `aldeed:collection2` and `aldeed:simple-schema` *should* be pretty straightforward. In your schema definition try:

```
POnumber: { type: String, autoValue: function(){
  if ( this.isInsert ){ // restrict to when inserting a document
    var currentNumber = incrementCounter('purchase order'); // this will use mongo-counter

    // WARNING: you can only ever get as rich as 10M POs!!
    var zeroPad = "000000" + currentNumber; // pad with 6 zeros

    zeroPad = zeroPad.substr(zeroPad.length-7); // restrict to 7 places 
    return 'PO' + zeroPad; // prefix with 'PO' 

  } else if ( this.isSet ){
    this.unset(); // prevent attempts to change the number
  }
}
```